# How to connect to Azure DB from any ip that uses azure (without 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255)?

Tags: database, azure

How could to connect to Azure DB from any ip that uses Azure,
Without setting the range 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 in the firewall?

Comment: By Azure DB, do you mean Azure SQL?

Comment: you can't.thats what firewall is for

Comment: it is better to have a proxy service/api layer which your clients call and that in turn interacts with the db and not let clients talk to db directly.

Answer (score 1):

If by `connect to Azure DB from any ip that uses Azure` you mean any applications running in Azure, then it is possible to do so. In the portal where you configure firewall rules, simply turn on "Allow access to Azure services".

[image]

What this does is that it creates a special firewall rule with Start/End IP address as `0.0.0.0`. You will not see this firewall rule in portal though.

To do this thing programmatically, simply create a new firewall rule and set the Start/End IP address as `0.0.0.0`.

However if your question is about any client IP address that connects to your database, then I would agree with @Aravind's comment above. You should not allow direct connection to your databases from anywhere but only facilitate it via a proxy service/API layer as mentioned by him.

Comment: AFAIK this does not create a rule `0.0.0.0` but only whitelists Azure's ip ranges. Which is what the original question is after.

Comment: Actually it does :). If you call list firewall rules on the server, you will see a rule called `AllowAllWindowsAzureIps` with `0.0.0.0` as Start/End IP address. Please see this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3nRZ.png

Comment: Must be a special case handled in the FW itself then, because shouldn't start and end `0.0.0.0` be zero whitelisted IPs?

Comment: That's my understanding as well.

Comment: It is a special case since 0.0.0.0 is not a valid address for a device.